# How do I add/remove or toggle classes based on the screen width?

Tags: javascript, resize, toggle, responsive, addeventlistener

Forgive me if this has been answered as I am struggling to find a similar scenario (which I find bazaar as I am sure this is a common script to run).

Basically, I would like to toggle or even add and remove a class based on the screen width. Below is my attempt at a script, where the eventlistener is working based on the colsole.log but I can't get the function to toggle the classes.

Basically, I would like to:

- turn class .mobile **on** and .desktop **off** for all elements that have the class .responsive, when the view width is less than 700px
- And then turn class .desktop **on** and .mobile **off** for all elements that have the class .responsive, when the view width is greater than 701px.

My attempt:

```
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var responsiveDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.responsive')[0];
  //for (var i = 0; i < responsiveDiv.resize; i++) 
  {

//responsiveDiv[i].addEventListener('resize', function() {

      if (w < 700) {
        //responsiveDiv.classList.remove('desktop');
        responsiveDiv.classList.remove=("desktop");
        responsiveDiv.classList.add("mobile");
        console.log("desktop Remove");
      } else {
       responsiveDiv.classList.add("mobile");
        console.log("mobile removed");
      } }
    });
```

(The parts that are commented out, are parts that I think need to go the script but they end up breaking the console log, probably because the syntax is wrong. )

Also if what I am trying to achieve is not the industry standard way of doing it, I am more than happy to be advised alternative ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You should probably have a look at [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), then you can avoid using JavaScript and implement the functionality purely in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the forEach method instead of a loop you can interchange that.

There were few mistakes in your code that are as follows:

- Mistakenly you have added = operator for a method.
- In the else statement you are not removing the class mobile instead you are adding that again.

Check below I have corrected the code Hope this solved your problem.

```js
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  console.log(w)
  var responsiveDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.responsive');

responsiveDiv.forEach((element) => {
console.log(element)
 if(w < 700) {
        element.classList.remove("desktop");
        element.classList.add("mobile");
        console.log("desktop Remove");
      } else {
      element.classList.remove("mobile");
       element.classList.add("desktop");
       
        console.log("mobile removed");
      } 

})

     
      
    });
```

```css
.responsive{min-width: 100vw; min-height: 100vh;}
```

```html
<div class='responsive'>1</div>
<div class='responsive'>2</div>
<div class='responsive'>3</div>
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough! If only had asked this question sooner! Thank you MD M Nauman :D

Comment: Always Welcome, If this answer resolves your problem then don't forget to accept this answer.